# How to get Start Date and End Date in Last month using Javascripts?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get Start Date and End Date in Last month using Javascripts.

For an example:

Today - 09/07/2013

I need to get output

Last month start date: 01/06/2013
Last month end date: 30/06/2013

Comment: var d = new Date();
        var to = d.setTime(d.getTime() - (d.getDay() ? d.getDay() : 7) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        var from = d.setTime(d.getTime() - 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
alert(to);
alert(from);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function f()
{
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()-1, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0);
alert(firstDay+"==="+lastDay);
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work if current month is January. It should give previous year's December but does not do so.